# Bootstrap 3 and Google Charts - formatting issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on the prototype for a sales volumes visualization tool and have come across a problem with the size of the Google Geochart being displayed.

This fiddle demonstrates my problem when you follow the steps below: http://jsfiddle.net/daKzQ/2/

1. Load the fiddle. Note the size of the Canada map.
2. Click on the Data table.  Note the size of the data table.
3. Click on the Graphs > Volumes by Province tab to return to the initial screen. The map size has changed!
4. Click on the Data tab again. The width of the data table has changed!

These changes to size are the problem.  I want to stick to the original sizes.

I tried doing:

```
<div id="graph_tab" class="tab-pane active" style="hight:100%;width:100%">
```

As well as using a number of pixel sizes to prevent this resizing from happing on the containing divs, but with no luck.

Does anyone know how to prevent this resizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to attempting to draw the charts/tables inside a hidden div.  The Visualization API has issues getting dimensions correct when drawing in a hidden div, so you must unhide the div before making a draw call.

Comment: That makes sense. If you redraw the chart while visible, it goes back to the desired size. Thanks for pointing this out.